# Parsing JSON with decodable issue

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I'm trying to parse `JSON` schedule data of weekdays and every weekday has array of different events/schedules that repeat each weak. So i have a data array that has weekday objects from monday to sunday and weekday has array of events/schedules.

```
struct Scheduledata: Decodable {
let data: [WeekDay]
}

struct WeekDay: Decodable {
    let monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday : [Schedule]?

}

struct Schedule: Decodable {

let id: Int?
let start: String?
let end: String?
let address: String?
let name: String?
let text: String?
let imageURL: String?
let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?


enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case text, location, start, end, name, address, id
    case imageURL = "image_url"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    text = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .text)
    imageURL = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageURL)
    location = try container.decodeIfPresent(CLLocationCoordinate2D.self, forKey: .location)
    start = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .start)
    end = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .end)
    address = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .address)
    name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
}
}



extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Codable {

public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    self.init()
    longitude = try container.decode(Double.self)
    latitude = try container.decode(Double.self)
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    try container.encode(longitude)
    try container.encode(latitude)
}
}
```

This is the json object I'm trying to parse

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "monday": []
    },
    {
        "tuesday": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "day_id": 2,
                "start": "16:30",
                "end": "21:00",
                "name": "Test Event",
                "address": "6 mohamed galal street cairo, heliopolis",
                "lat": "30.0866280",
                "long": "31.3236130",
                "image": "http:\/\/80.211.174.200\/img\/event\/1542547661.jpeg",
                "title": "Test_Event",
                "description": "This is just a test event to test the testable testi test test testit test............................. yes this is a test indeed",
                "created_at": "2018-11-18 15:27:41",
                "updated_at": "2018-11-18 15:27:41"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "wednesday": []
    },
    {
        "thursday": []
    },
    {
        "friday": []
    },
    {
        "saturday": []
    },
    {
        "sunday": []
    }
]
}
```

What I'm expecting is a dictionary:

`var schedule = ["monday":[schedule], "tuesday":[schedule], ...]`

What I'm getting seems like an array of dictionaries. I have only one day in each weekday object not all days of the week.

`var schedule = [["monday":[schedule], "tuesday":[schedule], ...],["monday":[schedule], "tuesday":[schedule], ...]]`

So how can i do it? I create a different struct for each day instead of the weekday struct? Doesn't seem logic. Something is not just right. I'm sure there is a smarter solution for parsing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

1: you declared many properties as Optional. When you do that, you hide the errors away. You want this to succeed or to fail during testing so you know where to debug, not sweeping it under the rugs with Optionals.

```
struct WeekDay: Decodable {
    let monday, tuesday, ... : [Schedule]?
}

struct Schedule: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let start: String?
    let end: String?
    let address: String?
    ...
}
```

2: your JSON is really hard to work with. If you have control of the server side, please change that to:

```
{
    "data": [
        "monday": [],
        "tuesday": [{...}, {...}, ...],
        "wednesday": [],
        "thursday": [],
        "friday": [],
        "saturday": [],
        "sunday": [],
    ]
}
```

---

Assuming you can't change the JSON, here's how you can decode the bad JSON:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

struct WeeklySchedule: Decodable {
    let monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday: [Schedule]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // Get the content of the `data` key from JSON
        var subContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .data)

        // Since you declare `monday`, etc. as `let` properties, they cannot
        // be assigned multiple time. And the compiler does not know how
        // many times the variable will be assigned to a `while` loop. So we
        // need to define some local variables to temporarily hold the values.
        var monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday: [Schedule]!

        while !subContainer.isAtEnd {
            let dailySchedule = try subContainer.decode([String: [Schedule]].self)

            // The `first` value of a dictionary is non-deterministic since
            // dictionaries do not have an order. But if the dictionary
            // contains more than one weekday, there's a problem with the
            // JSON anyway.
            guard let (weekday, schedule) = dailySchedule.first else { continue }

            switch weekday {
            case "monday": monday = schedule
            case "tuesday": tuesday = schedule
            case "wednesday": wednesday = schedule
            case "thursday": thursday = schedule
            case "friday": friday = schedule
            case "saturday": saturday = schedule
            case "sunday": sunday = schedule
            default: break
            }
        }

        self.monday    = monday
        self.tuesday   = tuesday
        self.wednesday = wednesday
        self.thursday  = thursday
        self.friday    = friday
        self.saturday  = saturday
        self.sunday    = sunday
    }
}

struct Schedule: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let start: String
    let end: String
    let address: String
    let name: String
    let text: String
    let imageURL: URL
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case start, end, name, address, id
        case imageURL = "image", text = "description"
        case lat, long
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id       = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.start    = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .start)
        self.end      = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .end)
        self.address  = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
        self.name     = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.text     = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        self.imageURL = try container.decode(URL.self, forKey: .imageURL)

        let latStr  = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lat)
        let longStr = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .long)
        guard let lat = CLLocationDegrees(latStr), let long = CLLocationDegrees(longStr) else {
            fatalError("lat / long is not a number")
        }
        self.location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }
}

let weeklySchedule = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeeklySchedule.self, from: jsonData)
```